# rs2xml does not display column names and the first row in my table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a query that returns the following

```sql
select tyear,sum(total) as total,sum(expected) as expected 
from 
(
select extract(year from date) as tyear ,sum(paid) as total ,sum(amount) as expected 
from term1 group by tyear 
union all 
select extract(year from date) as tyear ,sum(paid) as total ,sum(amount) as expected 
from term2 
group by tyear 
union all 
select extract(year from date) as tyear ,sum(paid) as total ,sum(amount) as expected 
from term3 
group by tyear 
)a group by tyear
```

From MySQL command line or workbench I get these results

```
tyear    total       expected
2012     30000       900000
2013     40000       50000
2014     320000      50000
2015     100000      200000
```

In my java code, I am using `rs2xml.jar` to display the table above. The problem is, it does not show the first row and it also does not display the column names.

The line of code below displays the table results

```java
table3.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

This is what I get in my java

```
2013    11000   13000
2014    772565  66071989
2015    65000   87000
```

Comment: table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

is the line f code that displays the result in my java cde